# Cannon add foreign keys

Tags: laravel-7

```
$table->string('game_id')->unique();
$table->foreign('game_id')->references('game_id')->on('servers');
```

in my game migration, and i got the following:

```
 SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL
```

: alter table `games` add constraint `games_game_id_foreign` foreign key ( `game_id`) references `servers` (`game_id`))

And my server migration:

```
$table->string('game_id');
$table->foreign('game_id')->references('game_id')->on('games');
```

How to solve this?
Note: the game_id on servers table should not be a unique as they can contain multiple servers with the same type of game.
I'm using relations on games route to display servers based on the same type.

Comment: Your foreign id should be unsigned big integer,  cant be a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define your foreign key `game_id` with the `id` of your `servers` table, so change `game_id` to `id` as reference, like :

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('game_id');
$table->foreign('game_id')->references('id')->on('servers');
```